# Can I delete images from Pictures folder? Are they redundant?

Tags: photos, photos.app

I have several gigabyte of images/photos in my Pictures folder on my Mac.
I also have the Photos Library and iPhotos Library bundles. I believe all my images/photos would have been imported into the these two libraries.

Does that mean that I can delete all my images/photos from the Pictures folder?

Comment: Could you explain why you don't just use Time Machine to back up your Mac and then delete the files? That would save you from deleting the only copy if you didn't have the photos imported. Also - explain what happens if you import one image into the mentioned library? Does it tell you that the file is a duplicate?

Comment: Over time the back up in Time Machine will delete older backups. So this won't work because I don't want to loose my images files. I simply want to save some disk space on my mac, I have copied these files onto a external hard drive already. @user3439894: You have edited out a very specific question, how do I compare the two libraries? it is a very genuine question. How do I list out the image file names in the two? so that I can compare them, bring the two in synch and delete one of them. If you want to ask a question please ask a different one, don't change mine just because you can.

Comment: @Ajay, I did not edit out any questions, bmike did as it's as he put it, "one question per question, please." Please look at the [revision history](http://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/226842/revisions) before making accusations.  If you have additional questions then you may ask another question and if you feel it's relevant you can always include a link to your previous question.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the photos have to be imported to one or the other via drag and drop or the import button. To be on the safe side import some of the photos into the photo application. If they are duplicates you will receive a popup stating that the files are the same